# Get a cheap, temporary SSL certificate that DOES NOT need exceptions

Tags: ssl

Where could I get a temporary (3-month) certificate for a low price? I don't need extended validation services, only a certificate which won't require users to confirm security exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [StartSSL Free](http://www.startssl.com/?app=1).

Comment: Tried that. Requires an exception to be set on the clients.

Comment: Work in XP(IE6 or Chrome) and Ubuntu(Firefox) without exception.

Comment: @Soumya92: could you please elaborate on when/where you needed exceptions? I never needed them

Comment: <<domain>> uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is not trusted.
(Error code: sec_error_untrusted_issuer). I get this error on every computer I tested.

Comment: You likely forgot to include the intermediate certificate. See http://www.startssl.com/?app=25#31

Comment: @agl That does seem to be the problem. I'll have it fixed soon, then. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of http://www.cheapssls.com/ - I'm in no way affiliated with them, but I've been a customer for a few years now and have never been dissapointed with their price point or range of certs.

Comment: Their store is closed. I'll check back later.

Comment: It seems that I was missing a step in the StartSSL config. Free is better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure those require a CA to sign them? So Verisign, or your provider (GoDaddy or similar) should have one for purchase.

Comment: I don't have a provider. That's what I am looking for.